# Announcement of two new specific close reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm glad to announce that we finally have 2 new specific *close reasons* that you can choose from the list of "community-specific close reasons".

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

These two close reasons reflect our [on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), where it's clearly stated that these questions are off-topic. If you have any comments or questions, feel free to leave them below :)